# Unable to hatch the following figure in the semicircular area

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: Manometer]

Hello friends, I am trying to etch the semicircular region similar to that in the tube in the following diagram, Please help.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (-2.4,0)--(-2.4,5);
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(0,5);
\draw [thick] (0,0) arc(0:-180:1.2cm);
\draw[thick] (-2.2,0)--(-2.2,5);
\draw[thick] (-0.2,0)--(-0.2,5);
\draw [thick] (-0.2,0) arc(0:-180:1cm);
\draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=green] (-2.4,1)--(-2.2,1)--(-2.2,0)--(-2.4,0)--(-2.4,1);
\draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=green] (0,2)--(-0.2,2)--(-0.2,0)--(0,0)--(0,2);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is the code that I have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the required final output but here is a heavily parametrized version:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\r{1.1}% Mid-tube radius
\def\t{.2} % Tube thickness
\def\h{5}  % Straight height (total height is \r + \t/2 + \h)
\def\lh{2} % Left height
\def\rh{4} % Right height
\path [pattern=north west lines, pattern color=green]
  (-\r+\t/2, \lh) -- ++(0, -\lh) arc (180:360:\r-\t/2) |-
  ( \r+\t/2, \rh) -- ++(0, -\rh) arc (360:180:\r+\t/2) |- cycle;
\draw (-\r-\t/2, \lh) -- ++(\t,0) (\r-\t/2, \rh) -- ++(\t,0); 
\draw [black, thick] 
  (-\r-\t/2, \h) -- ++(0, -\h) arc (180:360:\r+\t/2) -- ++(0, \h)
  (-\r+\t/2, \h) -- ++(0, -\h) arc (180:360:\r-\t/2) -- ++(0, \h);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]